# Netzke Grid filtering

Tags: netzke

I have an issue related to filtering data in Netzke Grid.

```
    column :user_id do |c|
      c.editor = {xtype: :combobox, editable: false, min_chars: 2}
    end
```

It is mentioned in the doc that,
A hash that will override the automatic editor configuration. For example, for one-to-many association column you may set it to {min_chars: 1}, which will be passed to the combobox and make it query its remote data after entering 1 character (instead of default 4).

Seems `{min_chars: 1}` is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see example below for simple Customers grid and let me know if it works for you. Netzke way is to use `__` (double underscore) to define one-to-many associations. This gives you combobox and all necessary data bindings. I tried different ways to make `min_chars` property work, but it all failed. Could be a bug. In the end, the only thing that worked is to do it from `init_component` method.

```
class Customers < Netzke::Basepack::Grid
  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = 'Customer'
    c.columns = [
      { name: :name, header: 'Customer Name' },
      { id: :country__name, name: :country__name, header: 'Country' }
    ]
  end

  js_configure do |c|
    c.init_component = <<-JS
      function() {
        this.callParent();
        Ext.ComponentManager.get('country__name').editor.minChars = 2;
      }
    JS
  end

end
```

Comment: Great, this works for me. Thanks for the nice work. You are giving such a fantastic support.